# how to detect spaces, special characters in html tags in python

Tags: python, html, regex

For the following input

```
I/O 1<   img   >    '<    input   >
I/O 1<'   img   >    '<    input   >
```

I want the required output as below and this should happen if `<` followed by space is present.

```
I/O 1<img>'<input>
```

Can anyone help me with regular expression?

Answer (score 2):

Try `<\s+`, `\s+>`, and `>\s+`:

```
import re

s = "I/O 1<   img   >    '<    input   >"
s = re.sub(r"<\s+", "<", s)
s = re.sub(r"\s+>", ">", s)
s = re.sub(r">\s+", ">", s)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
I/O 1<img>'<input>
```

Comment: I already defined my starttagopen = re.compile('<[>a-zA-Z]'), how can I modify to have above code

Comment: @Venu I don't understand. If you already have code you have tried, please edit your question and include it there.

Answer (score 0):

```
s= "I/O 1<   img   >    '<    input   >"
```

Find the starting of the html tag using s.find('<')

s[0 : s.find('<')] will select the substring from 0 to an index before the start of the html tag

s[s.find('<'):] will select the substring beginning from start of the html tag till the end.

s.replace(' ','') will replace spaces with no_spaces

```
( s[0:s.find('<')] ) + ( s[s.find('<'):].replace(' ','') )
```

Comment: hi, the spaces, special characters can be of any length. Thanks for the response. The main aim is to trim spaces, special characters after "<"

Comment: Hi, I just made an edit. Started from index of '<' using s.find('<')

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38561914/edit) to explain how this helps solve the user's question.